# python tic tac toe finding best move using minimax algorithm

Tags: python, minimax

I have build a small python tic tac toe game. There's a list `board_list = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. Bot player is assumed to be 1 which is "O" and human player is assumed to be 2 which is "X". Tic tac toe game is working as expected. But I want to improve the bot player to pick the best move using minimax algorithm. I have implemented the algorithm and it's working but it is not picking up the best move.

```
def minimax(board_list, depth, maximizing):
    temp_list = list(board_list)

    if is_board_full(temp_list):
        return 0

    if is_win(temp_list):
        return 10 if maximizing else -10

    if maximizing:
        best_score = float('-inf')
        for i in range(len(temp_list)):
            if temp_list[i] == 0:
                temp_list[i] = 1
                score = minimax(temp_list, depth + 1, False)
                temp_list[i] = 0
                best_score = max(score, best_score)
        return best_score
    else:
        best_score = float('inf')
        for i in range(len(temp_list)):
            if temp_list[i] == 0:
                temp_list[i] = 2
                score = minimax(temp_list, depth + 1, True)
                temp_list[i] = 0
                best_score = min(score, best_score)
        return best_score


def find_best_move(board_list):
    best_score = float('-inf') 
    best_move = None
    temp_list = list(board_list)

    for i in range(len(board_list)):
        if temp_list[i] == 0:
            temp_list[i] = 1
            score = minimax(temp_list, 0, False) 
            print('score', score)
            if score is not None:
                if (score > best_score) :   
                    best_move = i
                    best_score = score
    return best_move

current_player = 1
winner = False

while not winner and not is_board_full(board_list):
    if current_player == 1:
        best_move = find_best_move(board_list)
    else:
        best_move = int(input("Enter your move (1-9): ")) - 1

    board_list[best_move] = current_player

    if is_win(board_list):
    game_board(board_list)
    print("Player", current_player, "wins!")
    winner = True

    current_player = 2 if current_player == 1 else 1
```

scenario is like this :

- So first bot player (1) choose 0 cell
- Then human player choose 3 cell.
- Then bot player choose 1 cell.
- Then human player choose 2 cell.
- Then bot player choose 4 cell.
- Then human player select 7 cell.

The expected behavior is that bot player should choose 8 cell so it will be a win. But instead it always choose 5 cell.

So it is not picking up the winning move. Can anyone help me solve this

Comment: You're never resetting the computer move in your `find_best_move` function after calling the minimax function!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code:

- Near the end of your code there is an indentation issue: three statements need to be indented more to become part of the `if is_win(board_list)` block. I guess this could be just a problem you introduced in this question.
- In `find_best_move` you have not mirrored `temp_list[i] = 1` with `temp_list[i] = 0` as you have correctly done in `minimax`.
- In `minimax` you have this code:

  ```
  if is_win(temp_list):
      return 10 if maximizing else -10
  ```

  But the value you return is opposite to what it should be. Realize that it is not the current player that won the game, but the previous player, so `maximizing` is not reflecting who won the game. It should be:

  ```
  if is_win(temp_list):
      return -10 if maximizing else 10   # opponent won the game
  ```
- In `minimax` you are testing too soon whether the board is full. Even on a full board, it could be that the last move was a winning move. So you should first test for a win, and only then for a draw.

If you fix those issues, it will work (assuming all other functions like `is_win` and `is_board_full` were correctly implemented).